# JavaScript executes same function within different times

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Looking for the optimal solution for famous Ransom Note task, [(eg. from HackerRank)](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem), I was experimenting with the execution time of JavaScript function, when it iterates though arrays with different length (stepping a bit aside from initial idea of the task).

I was registering time it took to iterate through pairs of arrays with length: 
1. one thousand
2. ten thousand
3. one hundred thousand
4. two hundred thousand
5. hundred thousand.

Surely, I expected the time to increase with as array's length, and wanted to see the pattern behind it.

However, results surprised me: **same function performing same actions on the exact same arrays has significant execution time difference**. Sometimes.

I stored execution times for each length in one object, which resulted in the following:

```
veryVeryBigData:  {
  '1000':   [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0 ],
  '10000':  [ 12,  12,  12,  12,  12,  12,  12, 12 ],
  '100000': [ 1464,  5498,  5637,  5591,  5389,  5524,  5481,  5440 ],
  '200000': [ 5858,  21847,  22704,  22214,  21638,  21845,  21798,  21926 ],
  '400000': [ 64027,  91809,  92233,  90515,  92953,  92394,  93374,  104708 ]
}
```

As you can see, there is significant differences for some iterations for arrays of 100000 and bigger.

Would be really grateful if someone could suggest why it happens or recommend certain subject to look into for better understanding.

My code is below:

```
const ten = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" ];
const thousand = Array(100).fill(ten).flat();
const tenThousand = Array(10).fill(thousand).flat();
const hundredThousand = Array(10).fill(tenThousand).flat();
const twoHundredThousand = Array(2).fill(hundredThousand).flat();
const fourHundredThousand = Array(4).fill(hundredThousand).flat();

const wordsArrays = [thousand, tenThousand, hundredThousand, twoHundredThousand, fourHundredThousand];

const veryVeryBigData = { 1000: [], 10000: [], 100000: [], 200000: [], 400000: [] };

const checkMagazine = (mag, note) => {
  const start = Date.now();
  let iterations = 0;
  let result = "Yes";
  let magazine = [...mag];

  note.map((w, i) => {
    iterations++;
    const index = magazine.indexOf(w);
    if (magazine.includes(w)) {
      magazine.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      result = "No";
    }
  });

  const totalTime = Date.now() - start;
  veryVeryBigData[note.length].push(totalTime);

  console.log("Result: ", result);
};

const performChecks = (mags, ns) => {
  mags.map(magazine => {
    ns.map(note => {
      if (note.length === magazine.length) {
        checkMagazine(magazine, note);
      }
    });
  });
};

//for the sake of experiment I compare two identical arrays, as my goal is just to calculate iteration time
//do it 8 times to see different results

for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
  performChecks(wordsArrays, wordsArrays);
}

console.log("veryVeryBigData: ", veryVeryBigData);
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: why c++ tag is included?

Comment: c++ tag was suggested by stackoverflow and I assumed that it could be related to Node's V8 engine which is in c++

Comment: Did you go through the question wizard?

Comment: Did not know about it, will check it out and make updates, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the memory is a random process (a.k.a Random Access Memory).
When you perform "magazine.indexOf(w)", it's random memory access, to get to the location of value 'w' memory cell in the complete memory. So sometimes, it's slow, sometimes it's fast, based on how many memory cells it has checked in this random process. That impacts the time takes.

Comment: This is very helpful, Sharath, thank you so much! Will look deeper into that subject!